# Web site takes very long to load page only in running environment but not local

Tags: tomcat, delay, latency

I'm web developer in Korea.

Because of delays of our web application installed on running server(real, not testing) I'm writing this question.

1. History of deployment

I and my co-worker developed web application(website for system operator).

We developed and tested for it.

When we deployed it to real(running) server of customer which is financial company, we found that our web application takes very long time to load main page in real server.

We deployed it three times to correct high latency.

But that phenomenon happened on every time.

And it happened not only one time on each deployment, but every time to request to server like to load main page or to load sub page with menu bar.

On first deployment, we guessed that the cause of the high latency is configuration of firewall. From the company's policy the port was one-way so we guessed that way.

On second deployment, the financial company said that they changed port direction to bidirectional(two-way). So we conclude that port direction is not problem.
And on second deployment, we newly found ERROR log with STOMP of web application.
So, we guessed that the problem resulted from STOMP.

In third deployment, we updated the source to correct it. The high latency phenomenon happens still although the error related to STOMP was disappeared.

2. Phenomenon, Clue

Below are the phenomenon or clue of the problem.

- I deployed web application through Tomcat 7.0. Then the latency(delay) of web page loading was very high. It takes from 20 sec to about 1 min. 
  Even loading main page which has only login facility(like Google) takes long time. And on each new different page loading, it has high latency too.
  But the page opens always.
- Our web application is installed on Intel Zeon, CentOs and through Tomcat 7.0.
- On other computer on Windows 7, I tried to access to web application with familiar typing 191.xx.xx.xxx:7000/moduleName. And identical long delay(high latency) happened with Chrome and IE.
- When I requested normal access to controller, there was high latency on loading.
  But when I requested ajax call to controller, there was very low latency as if I run web application locally. That is, no problem with ajax call.
- There was no error log related http or connection on web application. 
  But the log printed out after latency phenomenon is over. 
  In Ajax call having normal(very low) latency the log was print out as soon as the functionality was ran.
- When I opened Tomcat's default page(dir path : .../webapps/ROOT, request address : :7000/ ), there was normal(very low) latency.
- Our web application has agent application and server application. In below source of agent application, HttpHostConnectException happened.

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(status_url);

// add request header
request.addHeader("User-Agent", "logpulse");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); // EXCEPTION HERE
```

- Accessing real(running) server is different from local(test) server.
  When I tested the application on local environment, I uploaded application tar file through Filezilla directly and I accessed directly to CentOS server through putty.
  However, when I saw file upload and server access on running server, there was 1 step more. 
  The operator uploaded file to different server and through put command, he uploaded file to running server which runs our web application.
  When accessed to running server, he accessed different serevr and through telnet command, he accessed running server.
- I checked up that there were heavy loads on running server through "top" command, 
  I was hard to conclude that it relates with latency because CPU occupation rates ranged 2~3% and memory occupation ranged from 20 to 30 percent.
- All these phenomenon happens ONLY running environment in financial company. But Not happens in local environment.

3. To end

Thank you for reading my long question.

I'd like very much if you would inform to me why the loading time is so long(20 sec ~ 1 min).

More greedy, I want to know how to replay the problem in my local environment.

Comment: Do you have remote access to the server? If so, take a few [thread dumps](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_obtain_a_thread_dump_of_my_running_webapp_.3F) a few seconds apart to see what your server is doing during those 20-second requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have remote access to the server. But I don't know what are thread dumps on the server so I'm going to look for it.

Comment: See the link in my comment: it will show you how to take a thread dump.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher. My boss solved it. It happened because of external resource such like web font or js using CDN. My local test network has no access restriction but real server has restriction to access to Internet. So as the source line using external resource is removed, the long delay is disappeared.